# How do I use blit() in the proper way in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I was trying to make a texture game, but it doesn't work with no errors. I'll show the code.

```
import time
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def Main():
    pygame.mixer.init()

    pygame.mixer.music.load(r"C:\...\OMFG+-+Ice+Cream.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.display.set_caption("3 Minutes Left!!!")

    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)

    intro_1 = font.render('3', True, (255,255,255))
    intro_2 = font.render('Minutes', True, (255,255,255))
    intro_3 = font.render('Left!!!', True, (255,255,255))

    time.sleep(1)
    screen.blit(intro_1, (140, 30)) #This isn't working.
    time.sleep(1)
    screen.blit(intro_2, (340, 30)) #This isn't working.
    time.sleep(1)
    screen.blit(intro_3, (540, 30)) #This isn't working.

Main()
```

I thought that the code screen.blit would work with while loops. So I tried.

```
import time
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def Main():
    pygame.mixer.init()

    pygame.mixer.music.load(r"C:\...\OMFG+-+Ice+Cream.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.display.set_caption("3 Minutes Left!!!")

    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)

    intro_1 = font.render('3', True, (255,255,255))
    intro_2 = font.render('Minutes', True, (255,255,255))
    intro_3 = font.render('Left!!!', True, (255,255,255))

    while True: #This isn't working.
        time.sleep(1)
        screen.blit(intro_1, (140, 30)) #This isn't working.
        time.sleep(1)
        screen.blit(intro_2, (340, 30)) #This isn't working.
        time.sleep(1)
        screen.blit(intro_3, (540, 30)) #This isn't working.

Main()
```

And I started the program. But pygame tab had no response. So i tried the screen.blit in a definition.

```
import time
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def Main():
    pygame.mixer.init()

    pygame.mixer.music.load(r"C:\...\OMFG+-+Ice+Cream.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.display.set_caption("3 Minutes Left!!!")

    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)

    intro_1 = font.render('3', True, (255,255,255))
    intro_2 = font.render('Minutes', True, (255,255,255))
    intro_3 = font.render('Left!!!', True, (255,255,255))

    while True: #This isn't working.
        screen_blit(screen, intro_1, intro_2, intro_3) #This isn't working.

def screen_blit(screen, intro_1, intro_2, intro_3): #This isn't working.
    time.sleep(1)
    screen.blit(intro_1, (340, 30)) #This isn't working.
    time.sleep(1)
    screen.blit(intro_2, (340, 30)) #This isn't working.
    time.sleep(1)
    screen.blit(intro_3, (340, 30)) #This isn't working.

Main()
```

Again, No Response. How can I fix this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window is not responding, because you don't handle the events. You don't see anything in the window, because you don't update the display.
A minimal typical PyGame application

- needs a game loop
- has to handle the events, by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- has to update the display [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html), by either [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) or [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update).

e.g:

```py
def Main():
    # [...]

    while True: #This isn't working.

        # handle the events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.quit()

        # draw the scene
        screen.blit(intro_1, (340, 30))

        # update the display
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the screen every time you draw/blit something to it, otherwise the changes won't show.

It doesn't matter whether you change things inside a loop or in a function, what matters is that you update the screen by calling either `pygame.display.flip()`, which updates the entire screen, or `pygame.display.update()`, which updates the entire screen or the rectangle passed to it. In this example I used the rectangle returned by blitting to only update the specific area, and also added a simple game loop that handles events, so your game will be responsive and you can exit it:

```
import time
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def Main():
    pygame.mixer.init()

    pygame.mixer.music.load(r"C:\...\OMFG+-+Ice+Cream.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.display.set_caption("3 Minutes Left!!!")
    pygame.display.update() # Update screen after filling it

    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)

    intro_1 = font.render('3', True, (255,255,255))
    intro_2 = font.render('Minutes', True, (255,255,255))
    intro_3 = font.render('Left!!!', True, (255,255,255))

    time.sleep(1)
    pygame.display.update(screen.blit(intro_1, (140, 30)))
    time.sleep(1)
    pygame.display.update(screen.blit(intro_2, (340, 30))) 
    time.sleep(1)
    pygame.display.update(screen.blit(intro_3, (540, 30)))

    while pygame.event.wait().type != QUIT:
        pass

Main()
```